# AgGrid issues( related to filter type )

Tags: javascript, node.js, ag-grid

I am using `AgGrid` with vanilla js.
And when I sort rows I get this error:

> Can not initialize because you are using a row model that does not contain all rows in the browser. Either use a different filter type or configure Set Filter such that you provide it with values.

Please let me know if anyone knows reason.
Thanks.

Comment: Please if possible, can you share some code snippets and error logs

Comment: are you using client side row model or server side?